# Copy values of an opened figure into a Matrix Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a saved matlab `.fig` file which has an image and I open the fig using `openfig`. I'm asking how I can copy the figure values in a matrix (lets say `img` which is `480x640 double`)to start doing some processing on it. If anyone could please advise.

Comment: what are exactly the `figure values`?

Comment: @scmg question updated with the fig file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty simple.  Assuming you have your figure open, first you need to make sure that you have a handle to the current figure, so perform:

```
h = gcf;
```

The data that is plotted in the figure is usually a child of the `axes` object.  The axes object itself is a child of the figure, so you need to access a series of hierarchical members before getting to what you need.  As such, you need to get the `axes` handles, then get the children of the `axes` handles
The data that is plotted is usually a 'child' of the Axes object. The axes objects are themselves children of the figure. You can go down their hierarchy as follows:

```
axesObjs = get(h, 'Children');  %axes handles
dataObjs = get(axesObjs, 'Children'); %handles to low-level graphics objects in axes
```

Opening your figure, I see that your data is of type `Image`.  In order to access the `Image` data, you want to access the `CData` field, and so you'll need to do this:

```
data = get(dataObjs, 'CData');
```

`data` should now contain your image data.  Therefore, here's the full code so you can copy and paste this into MATLAB:

```
openfig('input.fig')
h = gcf;
axesObjs = get(h, 'Children');
dataObjs = get(axesObjs, 'Children');
data = get(dataObjs, 'CData');
```

The above works up to MATLAB R2013b.  If you're using MATLAB R2014a and up, dot notation is what is used instead of the `get` function, and so:

```
openfig('input.fig')
h = gcf;
axesObjs = h.Children;
dataObjs = axesObjs.Children;
data = dataObjs.CData;
```

Comment: @shepherd - No problem at all.

Comment: do you know how I can set the image to `colormap(jet)` where only the non-zero values are considered so that the colorbar is correct?

Comment: Yes, set all zero values to `NaN`, then apply a `jet` colour map to it.  Do something like this: `data(data == 0) = NaN; imagesc(data); colormap(jet); colorbar;`.